# VueJS Toggle class to specific element in table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can’t seem to figure out how to toggle a class on a specific item in a table. I’m using v-for to loop over the data and printing it out to the user. The goal is to toggle a class when the user clicks on a specific element inside the table. When i’m trying to add a v-bind:class="{'active' : isActive} it just adds that class to all of them and not the specific.

```
<table>
     <tbody>
           <tr v-for="(item, index) in tableFilter"  @click="selectThis(item)" v-bind:class="{'active': isActive}">
                 <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Address}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Telephone}}</td>
                 <td>{{item.Email}}</td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>

export default  {
    data() {
          return {
              isActive: false,
              data: data
          }
    },
    methods: {
          selectThis(val, index) {
              this.isActive =! this.isActive
          }
     },
    computed: {
       tableFilter() {
           return data;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Any binding within an element using the `v-for` directive is going to apply to each element rendered by the `v-for`.

If only one element is to be active at a time, you could keep track of the active index:

```
data() {
  return {
    activeIndex: null,
    data: data,
  }
},
methods: {
  selectThis(val, index) {
    this.activeIndex = index;
  }
}
```

And use that instead:

```
<tr 
  v-for="(item, index) in tableFilter"  
  @click="selectThis(item)" 
  v-bind:class="{'active': activeIndex === index}"
>
```

---

If multiple elements could be active at a given time, you could keep track of each element's active status on the `item` object itself:

```
<tr 
  v-for="(item, index) in tableFilter"  
  @click="item.active = !item.active" 
  v-bind:class="{'active': item.active}"
>
```

Comment: You are correct! Thank you so much! Used way much time on this than i should. Have a great day :)