# Active a item inside a v-for loop when clicked

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am a bit stuck at the moment trying to figure out how to active the current clicked element inside a loop. Basically I just want to change some CSS to that item, for example `opacity`, and know where I actually clicking inside the loop (this one I can handle with `onclick` I think).

**So basically I tried this:**

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li :style="panel.color" v-for="(panel,key,index)in getPanels"
            :class="{active: panel === activeItem}" class="list-group-item"
        >
            A section {{panel.section}} was {{panel.action}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        activeItem: null
    }
},
```

```css
.active {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

The active class is not getting applied to the specific clicked item. What is wrong – can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS Toggle class to specific element in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824851/vuejs-toggle-class-to-specific-element-in-table)

Comment: where is the `@click` event that sets `activeItem = panel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has a couple problems:

- instead of `:style="panel.color"`, you should put in an object, so it should be `:style="{ color: panel.color }"`
- you forgot to add a click handler, i.e., you should add `v-on:click="..."`

Note: To simplify things, I didn't use your `getPanels` but use an array instead, it shouldn't affect how you understand how everything works.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    panels: [
      {section: 'One', action: 'Action 1', color: 'red' },
      {section: 'Two', action: 'Action 2', color: 'blue' },
      {section: 'Three', action: 'Action 3', color: 'green' },
      {section: 'Four', action: 'Action 4', color: 'orange' },
      {section: 'Five', action: 'Action 5', color: 'purple' }
    ],
    activeItem: -1
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler(idx) {
      this.activeItem = idx
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li 
        class="list-group-item"
        v-for="(panel, index) in panels"
        :class="{active: index === activeItem}" 
        :style="{ color: panel.color }"
        v-on:click="clickHandler(index)"
      >
        A section {{panel.section}} was {{panel.action}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```